# How to list all available methods of a class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

When extending a Java class, it can be very useful to have quick access to the implementation of all available methods, regardless of whether they are explicitly implemented in said class or inherited from one of its parent classes.

The closest tool that I have been able to find within Eclipse for this purpose is the "Type Hierarchy" view with the "Show all inherited members" option enabled. Unfortunately, that option really does show *all* inherited members, including the ones that have already been overridden in a parent class. This makes it difficult to tell at a glance *which* method implementation is the one that is relevant, and things become even more complex with the use of default methods in interfaces.

Is there an option, view, plugin or other technique that would allow quick access only to the method implementations that are relevant to a specific class, *including any inherited implementations*?

Answer (score 5):

Typing Ctrl+O twice in editor when a java type is selected pops-up an outline context dialog that displays the members && inherited members including default methods.

If a method is overridden, I think it shows up higher in the list?  So you can see which methods are overridden that way by seeing all the classes that implement the method but also which one is going to be executed by the order in the list?

Comment: This still seems to display all methods from the parent classes, including the ones that have been overridden...

Comment: That might help if I was looking for a specific method (although there are faster ways), but not when I am hunting for methods that need to be overridden. I would have to remember whether I have already seen a specific method signature higher on the list, which is not generally easy...

Comment: @thkala if you just want to see the methods that should/could be overriden what's wrong with source->override/implement methods ?

Comment: Hmm, you mean generating dummy overrides for everything, going over the overridden methods ("Open Super implementation") and then deleting everything that I don't need? It's what I do for new source code, but it's still awkward. It's also not very practical if you are reengineering or debugging existing code...

Comment: I see what you are getting at though. If you disable the "Group methods by types" option, you really do get a list of all overrideable methods - but with no mention of the source type and no easy way to jump to the implementation...

Answer (score 5):

If you are using STS eclipse click on the **Show View -> Outline** view.

- This will list all the members of the class *private* and *public*. Click on the particular member and this will take you to that particular method definition.
- The method names can be copied as well

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

/**
 * Compile with this: C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents\j>javac
 * DumpMethods.java
 * 
 * Run like this, and results follow C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My
 * Documents\j>java DumpMethods public void DumpMethods.foo() public int
 * DumpMethods.bar() public java.lang.String DumpMethods.baz() public static
 * void DumpMethods.main(java.lang.String[])
 */

public class DumpMethods {

    public void foo() {
    }

    public int bar() {
        return 12;
    }

    public String baz() {
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class c = DumpMethods.class;
            Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
                System.out.println(m[i].toString());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, `getDeclaredMethods` will not return inherited methods IIRC - you'd need to iterate over all parent classes and any implemented interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've clarified your question a bit, I believe I have an updated solution. This modifies the [MethodSpy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodType.html) tutorial.

Basically, there are a few changes to the original *MethodSpy*

1. The method name (i.e. Java.util.ArrayList.toString()) is replaced with just the method(i.e. toString()). We can use this with contains to see if any method, i.e. toString is only found once, where it has been defined last.
2. We iterate through all the superclasses and check if the methods are added. Notably, there are a few native methods that appear, i.e. `hashCode()`

This is the whole class. Modifications are noted in comments. There's probably a nicer way to get everything out, perhaps with Maps, but at the moment, it seems to be working properly with ArrayList from a cursory glance.

```
public class MethodSpyWithInheritance {
    private static final String fmt = "     %24s: %s%n";

    // for the morbidly curious
    <E extends RuntimeException> void genericThrow() throws E {
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
            while (c != null) {
                output.add("Methods in " + c.getCanonicalName()); //Add the class name to array
                Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods(); //get all the methods for this
                for (Method m : allMethods) {
                    String method = "";
                    method += String.format("     %s%n", m.toGenericString())
                            .replace(c.getCanonicalName() + ".", "");//remove the canonical name from the name of the method

                    method += String.format(fmt, "ReturnType",
                            m.getReturnType());
                    method += String.format(fmt, "GenericReturnType",
                            m.getGenericReturnType());

                    Class<?>[] pType = m.getParameterTypes();
                    Type[] gpType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
                    for (int i = 0; i < pType.length; i++) {
                        method += String.format(fmt, "ParameterType", pType[i]);
                        method += String.format(fmt, "GenericParameterType",
                                gpType[i]);
                    }

                    Class<?>[] xType = m.getExceptionTypes();
                    Type[] gxType = m.getGenericExceptionTypes();
                    for (int i = 0; i < xType.length; i++) {
                        method += String.format(fmt, "ExceptionType", xType[i]);
                        method += String.format(fmt, "GenericExceptionType",
                                gxType[i]);
                    }

                    if (!output.contains(method)) { //check to see if a method already exists, i.e. overridden
                        output.add(method); //not overridden, we can add
                    }
                }
                c = c.getSuperclass(); //get superclass and continue
            }
            for (String s : output) {
                System.out.println(s); //get output
            }

            // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample for `Java.util.ArrayList`

```
Methods in java.util.ArrayList
     public boolean add(E)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: E

     public void add(int,E)
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: E

     public E get(int)
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.Object
            GenericReturnType: E
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

     public java.lang.Object clone()
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.Object
            GenericReturnType: class java.lang.Object

     public int indexOf(java.lang.Object)
                   ReturnType: int
            GenericReturnType: int
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: class java.lang.Object

     public void clear()
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void

     public boolean contains(java.lang.Object)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: class java.lang.Object

     public boolean isEmpty()
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean

     public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)
                   ReturnType: int
            GenericReturnType: int
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: class java.lang.Object

     public boolean addAll(int,java.util.Collection<? extends E>)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int
                ParameterType: interface java.util.Collection
         GenericParameterType: java.util.Collection<? extends E>

     public boolean addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends E>)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: interface java.util.Collection
         GenericParameterType: java.util.Collection<? extends E>

     public int size()
                   ReturnType: int
            GenericReturnType: int

     public <T> T[] toArray(T[])
                   ReturnType: class [Ljava.lang.Object;
            GenericReturnType: T[]
                ParameterType: class [Ljava.lang.Object;
         GenericParameterType: T[]

     public java.lang.Object[] toArray()
                   ReturnType: class [Ljava.lang.Object;
            GenericReturnType: class [Ljava.lang.Object;

     public boolean remove(java.lang.Object)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: class java.lang.Object

     public E remove(int)
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.Object
            GenericReturnType: E
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream) throws java.io.IOException
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: class java.io.ObjectOutputStream
         GenericParameterType: class java.io.ObjectOutputStream
                ExceptionType: class java.io.IOException
         GenericExceptionType: class java.io.IOException

     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: class java.io.ObjectInputStream
         GenericParameterType: class java.io.ObjectInputStream
                ExceptionType: class java.io.IOException
         GenericExceptionType: class java.io.IOException
                ExceptionType: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
         GenericExceptionType: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

     public E set(int,E)
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.Object
            GenericReturnType: E
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: E

     public void ensureCapacity(int)
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

     public void trimToSize()
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void

     protected void removeRange(int,int)
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

     private void RangeCheck(int)
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

     private void fastRemove(int)
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

Methods in java.util.AbstractList
     public abstract E get(int)
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.Object
            GenericReturnType: E
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

     public boolean equals(java.lang.Object)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: class java.lang.Object
         GenericParameterType: class java.lang.Object

     public int hashCode()
                   ReturnType: int
            GenericReturnType: int

     public java.util.Iterator<E> iterator()
                   ReturnType: interface java.util.Iterator
            GenericReturnType: java.util.Iterator<E>

     public java.util.ListIterator<E> listIterator(int)
                   ReturnType: interface java.util.ListIterator
            GenericReturnType: java.util.ListIterator<E>
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

     public java.util.ListIterator<E> listIterator()
                   ReturnType: interface java.util.ListIterator
            GenericReturnType: java.util.ListIterator<E>

     public java.util.List<E> subList(int,int)
                   ReturnType: interface java.util.List
            GenericReturnType: java.util.List<E>
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int

Methods in java.util.AbstractCollection
     public java.lang.String toString()
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.String
            GenericReturnType: class java.lang.String

     public abstract java.util.Iterator<E> iterator()
                   ReturnType: interface java.util.Iterator
            GenericReturnType: java.util.Iterator<E>

     public abstract int size()
                   ReturnType: int
            GenericReturnType: int

     public boolean containsAll(java.util.Collection<?>)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: interface java.util.Collection
         GenericParameterType: java.util.Collection<?>

     public boolean removeAll(java.util.Collection<?>)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: interface java.util.Collection
         GenericParameterType: java.util.Collection<?>

     public boolean retainAll(java.util.Collection<?>)
                   ReturnType: boolean
            GenericReturnType: boolean
                ParameterType: interface java.util.Collection
         GenericParameterType: java.util.Collection<?>

     private static <T> T[] finishToArray(T[],java.util.Iterator<?>)
                   ReturnType: class [Ljava.lang.Object;
            GenericReturnType: T[]
                ParameterType: class [Ljava.lang.Object;
         GenericParameterType: T[]
                ParameterType: interface java.util.Iterator
         GenericParameterType: java.util.Iterator<?>

Methods in java.lang.Object
     protected void finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ExceptionType: class java.lang.Throwable
         GenericExceptionType: class java.lang.Throwable

     public final native void wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: long
         GenericParameterType: long
                ExceptionType: class java.lang.InterruptedException
         GenericExceptionType: class java.lang.InterruptedException

     public final void wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ExceptionType: class java.lang.InterruptedException
         GenericExceptionType: class java.lang.InterruptedException

     public final void wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
                ParameterType: long
         GenericParameterType: long
                ParameterType: int
         GenericParameterType: int
                ExceptionType: class java.lang.InterruptedException
         GenericExceptionType: class java.lang.InterruptedException

     public native int hashCode()
                   ReturnType: int
            GenericReturnType: int

     public final native java.lang.Class<?> getClass()
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.Class
            GenericReturnType: java.lang.Class<?>

     protected native java.lang.Object clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
                   ReturnType: class java.lang.Object
            GenericReturnType: class java.lang.Object
                ExceptionType: class java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
         GenericExceptionType: class java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException

     private static native void registerNatives()
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void

     public final native void notify()
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void

     public final native void notifyAll()
                   ReturnType: void
            GenericReturnType: void
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought about writing something like this on my own, but I lost my apetite when it came to handling Java 8 default interface methods, which is not trivial...

Comment: @thkala I have no idea if that means this is what you're looking for or not. Does Java 8 break this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code misses default interface methods entirely. Java 8 allows for method implementations in interfaces and then follows a weird most-specific-when-not-implemented rule to determine which implementation applies...

Comment: @thkala I just glazed over default methods. Terrifying. There's probably a way to get it, just need to read more into reflection.

Comment: It would involve some sort of recursion over all implemented interfaces, but neither BFS or DFS seem to fit. The frustrating thing is that Eclipse already has the code to do this - I just have not fould where (if?) it is exposed to the UI...

Comment: Oh, and I agree with the "terrifying" comment. Unfortunately default methods are also the one feature I found most useful in Java 8 - almost everything else is mostly syntactic sugar or library extensions.

Comment: @thkala I just tried this on 1.7 a simple interface and it's working fine (doesn't find a parent either). I don't have 1.8 on this machine so I can't test that part. I believe, for interfaces, the better option would be to not exclude the canonicalName in case multiple interfaces have the same method name but are implemented at different levels and for different purposes.

Comment: I tested it on 1.8 and it does not "see" the inherited default methods at all, as I expected. Unless someone points out something in Eclipse, I'll probably have to whip-up something on my own :-/

Comment: @thkala the current in the answer doesn't check the interfaces at the moment. I was wondering if you could run MethodSpy on the interface itself? If it can detect default methods in there, then it should be a quick fix.